# Vaadin generating grid with changed column names

Tags: javascript, java, css, vaadin

I just finished the [Vaardin Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/tutorial.html#framework.tutorial.overview) and I just realised that the column names of my generated grid are uppercase and for example "Birth Date" is split without doing so.

Someone maybe know why and where this is a thing?

Code: https://github.com/PIumpsKIo/vaadinTestApp.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> uppercase and for example "Birth Date" is split without doing so.

Yes, that is the default behavior. I.e if you have property "birthDate" in your Bean, the default caption in the header will be "Birth Date". If you want to have something else there, you need to use setCaption("My Caption") method.